# Screen Brightness not adjustable for Acer Aspire S3

Tags: 11.10, screen, acer, brightness

First of all, thank you very much for providing this useful forum.
Too bad for me, there is no support for the Acer Aspire S3 yet (just came out in October)

Short Description of the Problem:
I cannot adjust the screen brightness. Neither Compiz nor the FN Key combination work.
Also the fan keeps running on full power. As you can guess, both of these drain my battery.

The Setup:
Acer Aspire S3, Intel i5 newest Generation, Intel HD3000 Grafic Accelerator (no driver maybe?)

Thanks in advance, 
Kakadu90

Answer (score 13):

Hi I've had the same computer since two days ago.
To be able to set the brightness, I've modified the line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

to this:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="quiet splash acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor"
```

in the file `/etc/default/grub`, then:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Now I can set the brightness with the hotkeys, you can go so low that the screen is completely black...
I just have a problem when the screen goes to sleep; I can't get it back. (I have to close the screen to put the computer in sleep and reopen it...)

Have you found a way to get the touchpad scrolling functional?
And did you find the solution to set the fan speed?

Except for those little thinks it's a great thin, light and responsive laptop. I really hope those problems will be fixed soon.

Comment: Worked for me on Acer TravelMate 4750 with Ubuntu 11.10

Comment: Worked for me on Lenovo B Series..............

Comment: Worked for me on Acer (don't know which one) with Ubuntu 12.04 BUT I had to re-start for the change to take effect.

Comment: It fixed the brightness issue for me. However, now when I use the Fn key to adjust the screen brightness, the slider bar does not appear on my screen to show where on the spectrum my current brightness level lies. Not a big deal, though.

Comment: This also work for Acer TravelMate 8481.

Comment: Worked on Acer Aspire V3-571G with debian Jessie/Sid. Only the brighter/lessbright function keys seem to have swapped place and the gnome brightness slider does not appear.

Answer (score 1):

I too had this brightness problem. But it was fixed with the code

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="quiet splash pcie_aspm=force i915.i915_enable_rc6=1 acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor"
```

My laptop is Acer Aspire 4752Z (Ubuntu 11.10).

Answer (score 0):

I have an older Acer Aspire and have a similar problem - no backlight. After a look around the internet, I found adding `setpci -s 00:02.0 F4.B=00` before `exit 0` in /etc/rc.local will cause the backlight to turn on when the computer is turned on. Unfortunately, whenever I close my PC, I have to Ctrl-Alt-F1 it and run `sudo setpci -s 00:02.0 F4.B=00` to get the backlight to turn back on. If there is a way to get it to work other than that(and the GRUB) please tell me.