# battery backup issues on acer timeline 3830tg

Tags: 11.10, partitioning, battery, brightness, acer

I recently bought Acer timeline 3830tg for my studies and installed ubuntu 11.10 and currently using gnome-shell. I also have changed by graphics mode from hybrid to integrated mode to increase battery backup. With all this steps I have encountered some more problems. Could you please help to fix these issues:

1. Fan gives too much loud noise (does not even stop for single
   second this didn't happen in Windows)
2. Battery backup in Windows was 7 hours plus but it hardly shows 3
   hours in Ubuntu
3. I am not able to control screen brightness from keys provided
4. I had used gparted for partition. in one partition i have not
   kept single file/folder but then also it shows 34gb used

I would be very thankful if someone could help me to solve this problems as soon as possible, especially the battery backup issues.

Comment: Is this ubuntu fresh installed? Did you face any problem with ubuntu(unity ) default? install powertop: sudo apt-get install powertop .  run it in terminal : powertop .  install jupiter  which is a indicator applet helps to select processor mode [powersaver or performance etc]

Comment: i have installed fresh copy of ubuntu and also updated till date. the main problem is fan does not stop for even single second...and i am not able to control brightness too

Comment: maybe this thread will help your: http://askubuntu.com/questions/75219/screen-brightness-not-adjustable-for-acer-aspire-s3

Comment: fan and battery issue solved by following **Brightness control** steps of the post (http://www.linlap.com/wiki/acer+aspire+s3)

Answer (score 1):

I am also using acer aspire 5742 laptop.

I made changes in `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` and `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` to /etc/default/grub
`- GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pcie_aspm=force"`
`- GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_osi=Linux"`
and after adding these lines update grub from terminal by executing

`sudo update-grub`

By default the above lines will be different please check it and modify it.

If you are using sandbridge processor then after making change refer

[Laptop minimal power consumption tweaks](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67965/laptop-minimal-power-consumption-tweaks)

And then check hows the performance and the operation of `fn` key