# Raise and lower screen brightness (both from menu and from keyboard)

Tags: keyboard, xfce, brightness

I'm working on an Acer Aspire E15 with Ubuntu Studio 14.04 installed in dual-boot with Windows 8.1, and from Ubuntu I'm not able to modify the screen brightness, for two reasons.

The first is that I don't find the option in the settings menu.

The second is that if I use the keyboard commands (Fn+left/right arrow) I receive this on-screen notification:

[image: luminosity notification]

Despite the blue bar you see in the notification moves itself according to what I press, the brightness doesn't change.

On Windows I don't have such problem, so I know it's not an hardware issue.

How can I proceed to make it work?

UPDATE:

I tried [this](http://itsfoss.com/fix-brightness-ubuntu-1310/) solution, but nothing has changed.

UPDATE 2:

Also [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75219/screen-brightness-not-adjustable-for-acer-aspire-s3?rq=1) solution didn't work.

UPDATE 3:

The problem solved itself after an automatic system update shortly after I posted this message. But now I noticed it reappeared. So I'm undeleting this post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed [this](http://itsfoss.com/fix-brightness-ubuntu-1310/) solution and it worked.